# Why does my code using piping hang?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, posix, freeze

I have the following code:

```
 switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
           /*error case*/
           error = errno;
           printf("fork error(1): %s\n", strerror(error));
           break;

        case 0: //child case: execute remove_non_alpha and send result to pfd write end
            remove_non_alpha(arg_str);

            res = write(pfd[1], arg_str, arg_str_size);
            if(res != arg_str_size)
            {
                return -1;
            }

            char *arg_str2 = NULL;
            res = read(pfd[0], &arg_str2, 1); //hang happens right here

            break;

        default:
            /*parent case-- fall through*/ 
            break;
    }
```

pfd is created using *pipe()*.  *arg_str* is a non-empty char * string, and *arg_str_size* is an int equal to the size of *arg_str*.  I added the *read()* call as a debugging statement to make sure that my data was successfully written to the pipe.  However, when I call it, the call hangs indefinitely.   Can someone help explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be a better question if this was in a form where people could play with it. Ideally something that compiles as-is.

Comment: You should make two pipes if you want to both read and write. Trying to `read()` a value into a pointer is definitely not going to do what you're hoping. You need to allocate some memory and read into that, not read into the pointer.

Comment: GNU C Library pipe example: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html

Comment: @PaulGriffiths pipe() makes a pair.  But I agree reading into a null pointer is bad.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, I know, but having two processes both reading and writing from the same pipe is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, as I had in an answer, which was downvoted by someone. Piped data is destroyed as read, can't be read twice by two different processes effectively.

Comment: @Paul: `pipe(2)` makes a single *unidirectional* pipe.  You can write from one end to the other, but the other end can't write back to the first end.  If you want a *bidirectional* pipe, you need two pipes (each of which was its own read and write end).

Comment: @AdamRosenfield [pipe(2)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html) writes a *pair* of file descriptors into the supplied array.  You are correct about their proper use, am unsure what the point is here.  The improper use by the OP has predictable consequences illustrated in the answer I posted below.

Comment: @Paul: Yes I know it writes a pair of file descriptors into the supplied array, but they're not read-write FDs: one is read-only and the other is write-only.  You can't use a single pipe (pair of FDs) for bidirectional communication because the moment you have two readers or two writers on the same FD, you're going to have data races and/or a reader reading the very data it wrote (rather than that going to the other reader).  You need 4 FDs (2 pipes) if you want bidirectional communication in order for each reader and each writer to have its own set of FDs.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield Yes, I agree. The question doesn't seem to ask for that, though.  Nor am I trying to advocate such a wrong-headed approach in my answer.  This all seems to stem from the OP wanting to test whether the pipe write worked or not.  He attempts to test by reading from the read side of the pipe what was written in the write side of the pipe, and then wonders why it hangs (possibly because the parent also reads, not shown; or he reads into a NULL pointer).  Therefore, I don't think an answer showing a pair of pipes is on-topic here. Such an answer is for a different question...

Comment: @Paul: Ok, I think we're on the same page then.  It's not clear what exactly the OP is intending to do in his code, since reading and writing the pipe from the child process is an unusual thing to do and is rarely the right thing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate some memory to `read()` into. Right now you're trying to `read()` *into the pointer*, rather than reading into some memory that the pointer is pointing to.

That being said, although what you're doing isn't going to work, it shouldn't cause `read()` to block. You're only trying to `read()` 1 byte, and a pointer is valid memory, even if it doesn't make sense to `read()` into it like you're doing. There's a lot of code you're not showing, so your problem is likely somewhere else. In principle, what you're doing should work, like so:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    char mystring1[] = "Some output";
    char mystring2[100] = {0};

    int pfd[2];
    if ( pipe(pfd) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ( write(pfd[1], mystring1, sizeof mystring1) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling write()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if ( read(pfd[0], mystring2, 100) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling read()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Read '%s' from pipe.\n", mystring2);

    if ( close(pfd[0]) == -1 || close(pfd[1]) == -1 ) {
        perror("error calling close");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./sillypipe
Read 'Some output' from pipe.
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Your best strategy is to simplify your program until you hit the thing that's going wrong. It's not clear, for instance, how you're demonstrating that `read()` really is what's causing your program to hang, rather than something it's doing later, and you don't show what your parent process might be doing with that pipe, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

With a little effort one can make a self-contained example that works properly for the usually **useless case of reading and writing the pipe in only one of the processes**.

I say *useless* because the point of having a pipe is usually to *communicate between different processes*.

Minor differences aside, it is similar to @Paul Griffiths above.

working.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int go(){

  int pfd[2];
  const char *arg_str = "Can you read it now\n"; 
  int arg_str_size = 20;
  int res;
  char arg_str2[30];

  if (pipe (pfd))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return -999;
    }

  switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
           fprintf(stderr, "fork error(1) \n");
           break;

        case 0: //child case: send result to pfd write end
      res = write(pfd[1], arg_str, arg_str_size);
      if(res != arg_str_size)
            {
          return -1;
            }

      res = read(pfd[0], &arg_str2, arg_str_size); //won't hang because unread by parent

      fprintf(stderr, "read: %s \n", arg_str2);

      break;

    default:
      /*parent case-- fall through*/ 
      break;
    }
 return 0;
}

void main(){
  int x = go();
}
```

Notice that some space is allocated for `char arg_str2[30];` If instead, as in the OP code, the code used `char *arg_str2 = NULL;` which is undefined behaviour, and could result in an error signal like SIGSEGV (segmentation violation), etc.

**Don't do the following:** If both parent and child read from the same pipe, one will block.

If you want both parent and child to be able to read and write, then you need two pipe() calls.  If you are trying to test in the code to ensure correctness, test only the error indicators from reading and writing, do not test by reading back from a pipe what was just written.  **A pipe is a special kind of file, not an ordinary disk file.**

Data written into a pipe is written into a first-in-first-out (FIFO) queue, and deleted once read.  Reading an empty pipe will block (wait), which can seem like a hang.

We can see that behavior here.  With both processes reading the pipe (which code **can but shouldn't ** do) one process will read the contents of the pipe, but the other will hang.

hang.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int go(){

  int pfd[2];
  const char *arg_str = "Can you read it now\n";
  int arg_str_size = 20;
  int res;
  char arg_str2[30];

  if (pipe (pfd))
    {
      fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
      return -999;
    }

  switch(fork())
    {
        case -1:
           fprintf(stderr, "fork error(1) \n");
           break;

        case 0: //child case: send result to pfd write end
      res = write(pfd[1], arg_str, arg_str_size);
      if(res != arg_str_size)
            {
          return -1;
            }

      res = read(pfd[0], &arg_str2, arg_str_size); 

      fprintf(stderr, "child read: %s \n", arg_str2);

      break;

    default:
      /*parent case-- try to read here as well (not a good idea) */ 
      res = read(pfd[0], &arg_str2, arg_str_size); 
      fprintf(stderr, "parent read: %s \n", arg_str2);
      break;
    }
 return 0;
}

void main(){
  int x = go();
}
```

To get the child to block instead of the parent, add some `sleep()` calls so that the child reads second and so that the parent sticks around after reading.

Final Note: As you might imagine, filling in the rest of the C code from your example takes time and delays getting an answer.  Often times, if you go to the trouble of constructing  good test cases, or "Minimum Complete Verifiable Example" [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you will be able to answer your own question!

Comment: Not sure why you keep getting downvoted on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You are deadlocking the content what you are doing is first reading and then writing. If you put fprintf before fscanf for at least one process it will continue

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
int child_to_parent[2];
int parent_to_child[2];
pipe(child_to_parent);
pipe(parent_to_child);

pid_t id = fork();

if (id == 0) {
    close(parent_to_child[1]);
    close(child_to_parent[0]);
    FILE* out = fdopen(child_to_parent[1], "w");
    FILE* in = fdopen(parent_to_child[0], "r");

    char msg[7];

    fprintf(out, "hi\n");
    fflush(out);

    fscanf(in ,"%s", msg);
    printf("Child got: %s\n", msg);


    printf("Child sent: hi\n"); 

} else {
    close(parent_to_child[0]);
    close(child_to_parent[1]);
    FILE* in = fdopen(child_to_parent[0], "r");
    FILE* out = fdopen(parent_to_child[1], "w");

    fprintf(out, "hello");
    fflush(out);
    printf("Parent sent: hello\n");

    char msg[4];
    fscanf(in, "%s", msg);
    printf("Parent got: %s\n", msg);

}
```

Also don't forget to add \n to fprintf as fscanf will wait newline. As you see for buffering mentioned flushing will help,